# When does kafka producer start clocking linger.ms

Tags: apache-kafka

[Here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html), for batch.size:

> This setting gives the upper bound of the batch size to be sent.
> If we have fewer than this many bytes accumulated for this partition,
> we will 'linger' for the linger.ms time waiting for more records to
> show up. This linger.ms setting defaults to 0, which means we'll
> immediately send out a record even the accumulated batch size is under
> this batch.size setting

So when does system start clocking the time to track linger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock starts when the batch is created, i.e when the first record is added to it, i.e. the first time the app calls `.send()` for that partition since the last time the Kafka client sent a batch (or since the app started if it's the first batch).

This batch will then be closed and sent when it's full (i.e. when `batch.size` is reached) or when `linger.ms` milliseconds have elapsed since the batch was created, whichever comes first.

`linger.ms = 0` is essentially equivalent to no batching, which optimizes latency at the expense of throughput.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when send() is invoked for current batch, clock starts ticking and new batch preparation(ie adding record to batch) is also started. And when batch.size is achieved or linger.ms threshold is achieved(whichever first), send would be invoked with this batch. If linger.ms is zero then batch is immediately send as batchsize is an upper bound.

Comment: Yes, `.send()` is something that us developers have control over, whereas the actual emission of batches to the brokers is a configurable "behind the scene" mechanism. Keep in mind that there is one such batch per partition (not per topic), so the whole logic of waiting for a batch to be old enough or full enough is per partition (that's essentially because the kafka broker where to send the data is typically different for each partition, which helps  balancing the load across the cluster). You can also force the emission of the ongoing batches by calling `flush()`.

Comment: ok, and it also means that in same request we can have batches for different partitions...